# using xdmp:eval in REST Service in Marklogic

Tags: rest, xquery, marklogic

I am using the below REST service to insert the document(from DB Ingestion) into Rest DB which is configured for this service. I am using POST method and sending parameters in form-data.

URL: `http://{hostname}:8010/v1/addDocument`.

The issue is that the `xml($DirectoryListing)` picked from Ingestion DB is getting automatically serialized into text, so I am not getting the xml for insertion.
This is working fine when this code is directly ran on Qconsole, but from rest service call its not working.

ML Version I am using is 7.0-2.3​

Please help me on this.

```
let $PrefixURI := "/docs/"

let $Path := fn:concat('/processing/',$transId,'/validDocs/')
let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("Path",$Path))
let $DirectoryListing as node() := 
            xdmp:invoke-function(
                    function() {
                      xdmp:directory($Path)
                    } ,
            <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
              <database>{xdmp:database("Ingestion")}</database>
            </options>
        )


let $logs := 
element docsUris {
    for $FileEntry in $DirectoryListing
        let $Filename := functx:substring-after-last(xdmp:node-uri($FileEntry),'/')
        let $docUri := fn:concat($PrefixURI, $Filename)
        let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("uri",$docUri))
        let $contents := $FileEntry
        let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("adding document",$contents))
        return 
                      (: Insert the document :)
              (dls:document-insert-and-manage(
               $docUri,
                fn:false(),
               $contents,
                "created",
                (xdmp:permission("dls-user", "read"),
                 xdmp:permission("dls-user", "update")),
                "historic"),
              xdmp:document-add-collections(
               $docUri,
                "latest"),
              xdmp:document-remove-collections(
                    $docUri,  "historic")


               )
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in REST API or your own custom built? If the built-in, http://{hostname}:8010/v1/addDocument should be http://{hostname}:8010/v1/documents.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are getting the full contents of the document, but as text instead of XML, correct?

Comment: To footnote Dave's comment, if you want to extend the built-in REST API, the URI would be /v1/resources/YOUR_SERVICE and the payload would need to be multipart/mixed -- see
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions

Comment: Yes, I am getting full contents of the document as text instead of xml.

Comment: I am using Custom built API  module-invoker.xqy?format=xml&moduleName=add-document&requestDirectory=add&apiVersion=v1